# How to block an ip range of a country through blogger account?

Tags: javascript, html, ip, adsense, country

I have to stop click bombing and unusal clicks from a Country. Can you tell me any HTML and javasript code to do such thing in my blogger, so that my adsense acount never get banned again.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to solve this on the backend. This isnt really a HTML and javascript problem.

Answer (score -2):

I can show you where a free and maintained list of [ip ranges by country is available](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite).

The exact implementation can vary, you may want to use your htaccess file, or your blogging software may have its own a method ... or something else entirely.